# How to get the word which is in first quotation marks?

Tags: php, regex

Let's say I have the this text (not to be treated as PHP code):

```
$this->validation->set('username','username','trim');
$this->validation->set('password','password','trim');
$this->validation->set('password2','password2','trim');
$this->validation->set('name','name','trim');
$this->validation->set('surname','surname','trim');
```

I want to get the list of first words after `set(` which is in quotation marks in every line, so the output of previous input must be like this:

```
username
password
password2
name
surname
```

I think, it's possible with regular expressions. My question is how can I get the list of the words which is in first quotation marks with PHP?

Comment: it's apparently a PHP code and you shouldn't treat is as text.

Comment: ok, lets say the text is like this : `this->validation->set('surname','surname','trim'); ` I mean without dollar sign. Then is it possible ?

Comment: If it always looks like this, you can easily do it with string functions. @Your Common Sense PHP might not seem the right tool, but why not?

Comment: @jeroen can you write example code,please ?

Comment: You'd split the text line into individual lines, find the positions of the 1st and 2nd quotes in each line using string search operations, then extract the text between those two positions to get your word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Lets say the variable `$text` holds the data from your question.
- Let's analyse the regular expression `/set\('(.*?)'/`:

  - `/` is the delimiter.
  - `set\('` and `'` are the strings `set('` and `'`, respectively.
  - `.*?` is the least amount of (arbitrary) characters between the two aforementioned strings.<sup>1</sup>
  - As a result, this regular expression matches:

    `$this->validation->set('`**`username`**`','username','trim');`
- To store all the strings you need in the array `$matches[1]`, we can use the function [`preg_match_all`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php).

  It suffices to call `preg_match_all("/set\('(.*?)'/", $text, $matches)`.

<sup>1</sup> See also: [Regex Tutorial - Repetition with Star and Plus - Laziness Instead of Greediness](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy)

**Example code:**

```
$text = <<<EOF
\$this->validation->set('username','username','trim');
\$this->validation->set('password','password','trim');
\$this->validation->set('password2','password2','trim');
\$this->validation->set('name','name','trim');
\$this->validation->set('surname','surname','trim');
EOF;
preg_match_all("/set\('(.*?)'/", $text, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$arr = explode("'","this->validation->set('surname','surname','trim')");

print_r($arr);
```

not sure why you would want to do something like that, but the above should work